# Cannot connect remotely to mongodb installed on AWS instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, rhel7

I have installed and started mongodb on my RHEL AWS instance. Now I want to connect to the mongodb server from my local machine but am not able to do so.

I have made changes to the bind_ip parameter in the mongodb.conf file and also have added rules to the security group for the AWS instance to allow connections on port 27017 for any inbound request. Am I missing anything ??

MongoDB Version - 3.4.14
AWS Instance - RHEL

Thanks in advance !!!

Adding the mongod.conf file

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /home/ec2-user/AutoMaTics/setup/dbData
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
#  bindIpAll: true
# bindIp: 127.0.0.1,13.127.31.137  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: what does error logs say ?

Comment: adding only last lines
`2018-05-06T12:30:41.079+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 125.99.217.65:24100 #1 (1 connection now open)
2018-05-06T12:30:45.699+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 125.99.217.65:24101 #2 (2 connections now open)
2018-05-06T12:31:14.703+0000 I -        [conn2] end connection 125.99.217.65:24101 (2 connections now open)`

Comment: try telnet <your_mongo_host_ip> 27017 from your local machine to test connectivity

Comment: telnel is working fine i am able to connect via telnet

Comment: What happens if you try to connect to from the mongo shell? You're not saying if you are using the mongo shell from your local machine or your application.

Comment: If tried connecting using mongobooster where I am getting timed out exception. And if i try to connect via mongo shell then it just gives me the message connecting to <Public IP>:27017 and nothing comes up.